# How to return Query Builder with a PostgreSQL CTE query

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent, common-table-expression

I have a query which I used PostgreSQL CTE(Common Table Expressions) feature :

```
WITH tmp_users AS (
  SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email, users.created_at,sum(transactions.amount) as credit
  FROM users INNER JOIN transactions 
    ON users.id = transactions.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id,users.name,users.email, users.created_at, transactions.user_id
)
SELECT * FROM tmp_users WHERE credit > 100;
```

I can achieve the results with this :

```
$result = DB::select("WITH tmp_users AS (
  SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email, users.created_at,sum(transactions.amount) as credit
  FROM users INNER JOIN transactions 
    ON users.id = transactions.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id,users.name,users.email, users.created_at, transactions.user_id
) SELECT * FROM tmp_users WHERE credit > 100");
```

But I need the **Query Builder** not only the results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S:**

Why I used postgres CTE feature?

Because in PostgreSQL if I want to do any statements on alias fields, I need to use CTE feature([Read more](http://sqlmag.com/blog/tip-apply-and-reuse-column-aliases)).

Comment: You can get the same result (with better performance) by using a subquery and `select *` from that.

Comment: I added a where to the above query. Now, can I get the same result by using sub-query?

Comment: Yes, of  course.

Comment: `But I need the Query Builder ` What is that, the *Query Builder* ?

Comment: See my answer..

Comment: I've created a package for common table expressions: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-cte

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, u.created_at
   ,sum(t.amount) as credit
   FROM users u
   INNER JOIN transactions t ON u.id = t.user_id 
   GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.email , u.created_at -- , t.user_id
) tmp_users
WHERE credit > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @wildplasser

```
$query = DB::table('users')
        ->select('*')
        ->from(DB::raw(
        '(SELECT u.id, u.name, u.created_at, sum(transactions.amount) as credit 
        FROM users as u INNER JOIN transactions as t ON u.id = t.user_id 
        GROUP BY u.id,u.name,u.created_at,t.user_id) as tmp_users'
    ));
```